# Through Cucumber-Protractor, unable to get Webpage Title

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumber

Through Cucumber-Protractor, I am unable to console Webpage Title in "Given" tag and all tests getting passed.
For me below Protractor.conf.js looks fine
Protractor.conf.js-

```
exports.config = {
//seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout: 60000,
allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},

specs: [
    'features/Login.feature'
],

cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/steps/logic.js',
    format: [require.resolve('cucumber-pretty')]

}};
```

logic.js-

In below code, unable to console the "webpagetitle" through disp()

```html
const assert = require('assert')
const {Before,Given,When,Then} = require('cucumber');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
 By = webdriver.By,
 until = webdriver.until;

var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var options = new firefox.Options();
options.addArguments("-headless");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
 .forBrowser('firefox')
 .setFirefoxOptions(options)
 .build();

Given('Go to Title', function () {
 function navigate(callback) {
  console.log("Getting Consoled - Getting to Google");
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  callback();

 }

 function disp() {
  console.log("Getting Consoled - Getting title");
  driver.getTitle().then(function (webpagetitle) {
   console.log(webpagetitle);
   console.log("Not getting consoled - This section has the issue");

  });
 }
 navigate(disp);
});

When('do nothing', function () {});

Then('do nothing here also', function () {});
```

Appreciate your help.

Error with @yong changes:
Do I need to call that done callback anywhere (as you have already called)?

> 

```html
1) Scenario: Add two number # features\Login.feature:5
   × Given Go to Title # practice\example6\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:173
       Error: function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 milliseconds
           at Timeout._time.default.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\Mohit.Garg\Desktop\Cucumber practice\example6\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:81:20)
           at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
           at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
           at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
           at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
   - When do nothing # practice\example6\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:173
   - Then do nothing here also # practice\example6\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:173
   √ After # practice\example6\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:173

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m05.006s
[16:00:07] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[16:00:07] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:00:07] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[16:00:07] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[16:00:07] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

C:\Users\Mohit.Garg\Desktop\Cucumber practice\example6>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Protractor` is build upon `selenium-webdriver` and implements the approach to control the async execution.  Because you use `selenium-webdriver` directly, you have to control the async execution of each Cucumber step function via `done()`

```
var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');

setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

Given('Go to Title', function (done) {
    function navigate(callback) {
        console.log("Getting Consoled - Getting to Google");
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/").then(function(){
           callback(done);
        })    
    }

    function disp(done) {
        console.log("Getting Consoled - Getting title");
        driver.getTitle().then(function (webpagetitle) {
            console.log(webpagetitle);
            console.log("Not getting consoled - This section has the issue");
            // call done() at here
            done()
        });
    }
    navigate(disp);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @yong for looking into it but now with your changes am getting errror "function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 milliseconds".

Comment: Updated question with error. Apologies I did not get your solution.

Comment: Did you get the output of `console.log(webpagetitle);` with my changes?

Comment: Updated my code, please try again. More detail about your timeout issue look at here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/timeouts.md

Comment: Thanks for the update but I don't think this issue is related to timeout.
I am not getting console.log(webpagetitle) but now this line is getting consoled " console.log("Not getting consoled - This section has the issue");"

Comment: update the code of function `navigate()`, try again.

Comment: Thanks @yong, you are a champ, it worked. Many thanks.

Comment: As you see, using `selenium-webdriver` directly to init `driver` is not a good approach to compose protractor script.  you need to manage aync/promise by yourself which will easy lead script run into strange problem and take your more time to debug and fix that problem.   Recommend you compose protractor script by using protractor api and the `browser` global variable which represent a browser instance.  `browser.get('http://example.com')` `element(by.css('')).click()`